# Datasheet for XC34064P wanted

Tags: datasheet

Usually Google guides me to http://www.alldatasheet.com/ or a similar site when I'm looking for a datasheet, but no such luck this time. The `XC` prefix reminds me of Xicor, but after being directed by Google to the Intersil site I couldn't find it there either.
Does anyone have a datasheet for the XC34064P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it as [MC34064](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=MC34064) at On Semiconductor.

Comment: I always thought XC was Xilinx and MC was motorola.

Comment: 'XC' is definitely a Xilinx IC designator; they had an XC3000 series in the late 80s early 90s, long obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

XC was the designator used by Motorola for their pre-release parts (experimental?), generally parts were developed as XCxxxx then released as MCxxxx.

Comment: Good info. Found a page mentioning this, and that they changed to PC: http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/6800/Motorola-XC6800B.html